# Single page site with scroll, can't get icons to change color when active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm struggling to get icons on the right of my website to change colour when viewer is on that specific page, so it's easily indicated what page the viewer is on.

The website is [www.summerfieldsflyfishery.com](http://www.summerfieldsflyfishery.com)

Comment: Link-only, zero-effort-shown questions are very much discouraged here -- please post the portion of your code that is relevant to the question as part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the active class of de `li` elements `li.active a {color:....}`